# Garbled text in GUI

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04, fonts, gui, wayland

This is what I see in some places on my Ubuntu 22.04 with Wayland and GNOME in a VirtualBox VM:

[image: VS Code with weird characters]

It's particularly bad in VS Code: the dialog window (which is supposed to be about settings sync) and the main window's title bar are totally garbled.

What causes this? And how to fix it?

**EDIT:** It's not just a problem with VS Code. This window's title should (probably) say "Report a problem…". There are two of them, both garbled (after waking the host system up from sleep; it's another problem, happens often, and no details are given, just a suggestion to report the problem, which one of the buttons does). There was a third one, not garbled. And windows like this ("Report a problem…") used to not be garbled, this is the first time.
[image: system window]

EDIT: I'll paste the other one as well. It's slightly different. Has something in the title bar.
[image: system window with some title]

Comment: Maybe it's Arabic?

Comment: The problem doesn't occur when I switch to X.Org. So I'm retagging to #wayland.

Comment: Thanks for reporting it. That's the only way problems like this will get fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this issue by unchecking "Enable 3d Acceleration" in my virtual machines settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can't confirm or deny. The problem has since disappeared for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78186386/encountering-distorted-displays-with-ubuntu-as-guest-os-on-virtualbox-with-windo/78186522#78186522